# Ubuntu Server 19.10 AX88179 driver problem

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu Server 19.10 with latest updates etc.
My problem is that I'm using a very old mainboard without a GBit LAN so I bought an external GBit LAN "adapter". Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

When I plug it in, it lights up for roughly 6 seconds and then the lights turn off.
When I do `lsusb`, it shows that it's still plugged in and is recognized.
`ifconfig -a` looks like the following:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether (*macadress*)  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.45  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::225:22ff:fe5c:776a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2003:c0:ff32:fe00:225:22ff:fe5c:776a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether (*macadress*)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1908  bytes 169364 (169.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 894  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 700  bytes 72274 (72.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx000ec65d0eff: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether (*macadress*)  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1260  bytes 89772 (89.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1260  bytes 89772 (89.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Where "enx000ec65d0eff" is the external GBit adapter.
By the way, the adapter is a "UGREEN USB 3.0 Ethernet Adapter".

I tried reinstalling the kernel, kernel modules and even tried to build that driver myself even though it's built into the kernel (5.3.0-40), but it doesn't complete and quits with error code 2 ("build-essential" and "linux-headers-generic" are installed):

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic'
Makefile:227: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:228: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:229:
Makefile:230: If you are building an individual subdirectory
Makefile:231: in the kernel tree, you can do like this:
Makefile:232: $ make path/to/dir/you/want/to/build/
Makefile:233: (Do not forget the trailing slash)
Makefile:234:
Makefile:235: If you are building an external module,
Makefile:236: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:237: ==========================================
  CC [M]  /home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.o
/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:816:3: error: ‘struct ethtool_ops’ has no member named ‘get_settings’; did you mean ‘get_strings’?
  816 |  .get_settings  = ax88179_get_settings,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   get_strings
/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:816:19: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_eeprom *, u8 *)’ {aka ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_eeprom *, unsigned char *)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_cmd *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  816 |  .get_settings  = ax88179_get_settings,
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:816:19: note: (near initialization for ‘ax88179_ethtool_ops.set_eeprom’)
/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:817:3: error: ‘struct ethtool_ops’ has no member named ‘set_settings’; did you mean ‘get_strings’?
  817 |  .set_settings  = ax88179_set_settings,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   get_strings
/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:817:19: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_coalesce *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct net_device *, struct ethtool_cmd *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  817 |  .set_settings  = ax88179_set_settings,
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.c:817:19: note: (near initialization for ‘ax88179_ethtool_ops.get_coalesce’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE/ax88179_178a.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1655: _module_/home/julius/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.19.0_SOURCE] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:30: default] Error 2
```

The really strange thing is that I checked the adapter with Ubuntu desktop live and got it running without taking further action.
So I think it's a driver problem.
Switching to Ubuntu Desktop isn't an option for me because I only got 2GB RAM and Ubuntu Server uses ~400MB at idle whereas Ubuntu Desktop uses well over 1.3GB.
`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` results in

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Comment: How have you set up networking in the server? Did you hope to simply plug it in and it automagically works? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks.
Just edited the question.

Comment: Hey @KnechtNoobrecht!!! I'm happy to know that you got your problem solved. But since this is an Q&A site, I'd encourage you to post what you did as an answer in the answer section and mark that as accepted once 48 hours of posting question have passed. For now, I have removed "the answer" from "the question". Thanks :)

Comment: @Kulfy ummm i already posted my solution but you changed it back to where i havent  (!?) seems shady...
Anyway, i reverted your change.

Comment: @KnechtNoobrecht and I reverted your revert.  **You are allowed to answer your own question**.  But to do so, solutions to issues need to be posted as **answers** and not as edits to the *question*.  (This is NOT a forum, it's a Q/A site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the OP (in [edits](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1215551/5)):

> Got it working by editing the file located in `/etc/netplan/` to:
>
> ```
> network:
>     ethernets:
>         enp1s0:
>             dhcp4: true
>         enx000ec65d0eff:
>             dhcp4: true
>     version: 2
> ```
>
> Thanks to [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555).