# How to connect an embedded linux system to pc via ethernet?

Tags: networking, drivers, ssh, ethernet, embedded-system

I have a custom board with a linux system and I want to connect it via ssh to my personal pc running ubuntu over ethernet.

With window I use putty to connect to the board, but in linux I don't know even how to start. How can I see if the board is even connected to the pc ? I need some drivers since  I'm using an usb-to-ethernet cable? And In general how should I proceed to connect my board and access to it with ssh ?

Thank you and sorry if the question is to general .

Also I think that the usb-ethernet adapter is not recognized as a eth connection, this is the output of:

```
ifconfig
enx74da38a00a64: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 74:da:38:a0:0a:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 22911  bytes 2117386 (2.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22911  bytes 2117386 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.184.118  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.0.191.255
        inet6 fe80::49a6:4288:5209:c39b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:fb:48:11:7c:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 115883  bytes 118945795 (118.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75655  bytes 12760493 (12.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and of:

```
 dmesg
[ 2424.429598] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2424.429771] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[ 2424.429795] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
[ 2424.429884] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64: Failed to read reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 2424.429889] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64: Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 2424.457188] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 2424.457194] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0001: -19
[ 2424.457199] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 2425.593875] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2425.621976] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2425.621982] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2425.621987] usb 2-1: Product: AX88179
[ 2425.621990] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[ 2425.621995] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000000000001CA
[ 2425.965607] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 74:da:38:a0:0a:64
[ 2425.985475] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx74da38a00a64: renamed from eth0
```

Comment: First of all, you actually have two questions, first is about the ssh connection and the second is about USB-Ethernet, please create two separate questions next time and search first, both of them were already answered.
SSH connection question was answered many times I think, here is the one of such questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761558/connect-two-local-linux-computers-via-ssh

And here is the one for your USB-Ethernet device:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215551/ubuntu-server-19-10-ax88179-driver-problem

Answer (score 0):

To find which computers are connected to your network you have to log in to your router. It shows a list of all connected devices and the IP for each of those connections. Most routers allow you to log in via a web browser.

Then you can install Remmina (or something similar) on your personal pc to connect to another computer on your network, for example the customer board you mention in your question.